# Java arraylist clear or reinitiate

Tags: java, arraylist

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(7);
        test.add(a);
        System.out.println(test);
        a.clear()
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

The output of test would be different(One is [[7]], the other is [[]])
If we use a = new ArrayList() instead of a.clear(), the result would be different. I thought the "test" had already recorded the "a" so I can do anything about "a" without changing "test".
Anyone can tell me what happens when I use a.clear() and correct my thought? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the "test" had already recorded the "a" so I can do anything
>   about "a" without changing "test".

It's recorded `a` by storing a reference to the same object that `a` holds. When you do

```
a.clear()
```

you are invoking the `clear` method on that same object.

Comment: How could I store the value instead of reference? I mean if I change the "a" by a.add(4); The whole "test" would change. But I hope test would stay the same. What should I do?

Comment: @Pugna You can't. The value of a variable is a reference to the object, not the object itself. `a.add(4)` is still adding to the object referenced by `a`. If you want to add to a different/new list, create one and assign a reference to it to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`a.clear()` removes all data inside the list. It directly effects the object a and its data. `a = new ArrayList()` will create a new ArrayList and assign its reference to the variable `a`. Since `test` stores the old reference of a the result is still [[7]]